# How did they shoot that scene in "The Fall"?

Tags: cinematography, the-fall-tv

Here is [the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrMUx.jpg) of *The Fall* I am talking about. It's from the first episode in the first season, in fact within the first ten minutes actually.

Here the character pulls of a mask and the camera is in first person POV. So, the mask is shown to be pulled off from the camera.

But in the mirror, it is shown that the character is actually pulling the mask off.

How did they shoot the scene? Is the mirror just a glass separating two identically arranged room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple a camera filming an actor.  Both the actor and the camera have masks that are swept upward at the same time.  To you and most of the audience, this is seamless.

However, if you freeze-frame, you see this.

[image]

Note how the angles of the mask on the actor and the camera are completely different, and the actor actually has his eyes shut at this point.

Comment: That's what my first thought was. So according to this theory, the mirror is actually a glass, isn't it? The mirror is a glass separating two identically arranged room.

Comment: There's probably no glass, just a hole in a partition.

Comment: Well, that's an irrelevant detail. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Steve-O It wasn't hard, I just hit the pause button on the video linked in the question.